# error when pushing changes to git from teamcity (ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/lib/ssh/ssh-askpass))

Tags: bash, git, github, teamcity

I am getting

```
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/lib/ssh/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory 
Host key verification failed. 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  
Please make sure you have the correct access rights.
```

This error occurs when trying to push changes to GitHub from TeamCity build.
How can I avoid this error message?

Answer (score 0):

The [TeamCity support page](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003083019-Failed-to-load-SSH-key-ssh-add-fails-on-windows) includes

> I needed to set the environment variable `SSH_ASKPASS` to point to "`C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-askpass.exe`".
>   This somehow overrides the unix path with the given correct one

That would assume your TeamCity is running on a Windows server.

Comment: after setting 
"set SSH_ASKPASS =C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-askpass.exe " also giving same error

Comment: @EaswarKumarAdireddi Did you check first that the path `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-askpass.exe` does exist? Also, what does `set SSH` returns? Do you see `SSH_ASKPASS` with the full path you just set?

Comment: @EaswarKumarAdireddi Did you add `SSH_ASKPASS` to the user environment variables of the account running TeamCity on your Windows? If yes, did you restart completely TeamCity, in order for that process to inherit the new user environment variable?

Comment: yes path exists but when i set it does not return anything

Comment: @EaswarKumarAdireddi Again, it needs to be set as a user environment variable of the account running TeamCity. See https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: i did !! but still getting same error 
i am doing below steps
**git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/project.git

git add -f %FileToCommit%
git commit -m "Adding file via build "
git push --force origin **

Comment: @Easwar What is the OS version and Git version TeamCity is using?

Comment: windows server 2008 and git version 2.11.1

Comment: @Easwar 2.11.1? Any chance to upgrade it to 2.25? Also be aware there is no more support for a Windows server 2008 (https://securityboulevard.com/2019/07/windows-server-2008-eol-end-of-life/: EOL)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207874/discussion-between-easwar-and-vonc).

Comment: this is the path 
C:\Windows\SUA\common\;C:\Windows\SUA\usr\lib\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\OpenSSH-Win64;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Nuget;C:\Program Files\7-Zip;C:\Program Files\Git LFS;C:\Users\ta230211\.dnx\bin;C:\Users\hs186016;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-askpass.exe;
this is path
but still getting same error
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/lib/ssh/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.