# what are the steps to push changes to git from teamcity using windows agent

Tags: windows, bash, github, git-bash, github-for-windows

need steps to git push one file to specific branch in git

```
git add -f %FileToCommit% 
git commit -m "Adding file via build "
git push --force origin
```

but this code giving Host key verification failed. error

Answer (score 0):

Under the account running those command (TeamCity is I believe [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60220358/6309)), runs:

```
ssh git@github.com
```

And type 'yes' when SSH asks for accepting the Host.

Then try again, and it should not give you "Host key verification" error anymore.